# passind data to bootstrap 4 modall

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

i want to place the variable in this link

```
<a href="#edit_task" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg fa-fw"></i></a>
```

here is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_task">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
```

my modal content

```
      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">add new user</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
```

display the variable here

```
      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">                          
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What data are you trying to pass? Is it a variable that you have in PHP or one in JavaScript?

Comment: a variabe in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript or jQuery when open the modal.

Your html tag "" change to this.

```
<a href="#" id="openModal" data-id="yourVariableHere"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg fa-fw"></i></a>
```

Your body modal

```
<div class="modal-body">
                  
  </div>
```

And in the jQuery like this

```
 $("#openModal").click(function(){
$(".modal-body").text($(this).data("id"));
$("#edit_task").modal("open");
});
```

Comment: and how do i display it in the modal

Comment: What data are you trying to pass?

Comment: the data-id assigned to the modal so that i may use it later in php

Comment: AW Mufid please assist me here

Answer (score 0):

You can echo your variable like this:

```
<?=$var?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to generate the modal dynamically. Your link should look like this:

```
<a href=".id<?php echo $variable; ?>" data-toggle="modal" title=""> </a>
<?php require('modal.php') ?>
```

Your modal.php file should have:

```
<div class="modal id<?php echo $variable; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Access the variable now -->
        <?php
            echo $variable
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```